# How to provide source-level debugging info when my compiler targets C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, gdb

I am working on a compiler that translate the source language into C. Then any C compiler could compile that into executable binary.

Though C compiler can attach its own debugging information with the executable, however, those are C-level information. For example, the stack trace displays C functions and line numbers in C, instead of the source code functions and line numbers.

I am pretty much concerned about the following debugging information available to users:

1. Stack trace of source-level function/line/file name, etc.
2. Value of variables to be printed as source-level value

What is the common approach to this when a compiler targets C?

I am looking at GDB's pretty printer. Will that be a possible solution to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are careful in your generated C, you can use as system like this.  Assuming that your source language file is `sourcefile.ext` and that you will generate `sourcefile.c` from this.

```
#line 32 "sourcefile.ext"
C code for line 32 of sourcefile.ext
#line 33
C code for line 33 of sourcefile.ext
```

However, note that if you generate multiple lines of C code like this:

```
#line 62 "sourcefile.ext"
first line of C code - will be treated as line 62 of sourcefile.ext
second line of C code - will be treated as line 63 of sourcefile.ext
third line of C code - will be treated as line 64 of sourcefile.ext
#line 63 "sourcefile.ext"
line of C code - will be treated as line 63 of sourcefile.ext again!
```

people can get confused.  You can 'deal' with that using:

```
#line 62 "sourcefile.ext"
first line of C code - will be treated as line 62 of sourcefile.ext
#line 62 "sourcefile.ext"
second line of C code - will be treated as line 62 of sourcefile.ext too
#line 62 "sourcefile.ext"
third line of C code - will be treated as line 62 of sourcefile.ext too
#line 63 "sourcefile.ext"
line of C code - will be treated as line 63 of sourcefile.ext
```

However, you can begin to imagine some of the difficulties. Ultimately, you need a native debugger for your language, but that is a daunting prospect.  Failing that, I've usually found it best to generate the `#line` directives as comments:

```
//#line 62 "sourcefile.ext"
first line of C code - will be treated as line 91 of sourcefile.c
//#line 62 "sourcefile.ext"
second line of C code - will be treated as line 93 of sourcefile.c
//#line 62 "sourcefile.ext"
third line of C code - will be treated as line 95 of sourcefile.c
//#line 63 "sourcefile.ext"
line of C code - will be treated as line 97 of sourcefile.c
```

Keep the C code around; debug in the C code, but the C code contains the line numbers that point back to the original source in `sourcefile.ext`.  You might consider including the source code in the generated C, too, so that the user can see what was written in `sourcefile.ext` while debugging in `sourcefile.c`.

I make no claims that this is pretty or good. In fact, it is pretty awful. But it does work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Following this, I found this directive in GCC manual. It works good enough. But is there a similar approach that allows to name C functions as source-level function?

Comment: No: I am not of aware of a mechanism that will allow you to manipulate the names of functions similarly.  You'd have to debug using the modified/transformed names. Usually, these are reasonably systematic (but C++ names take a bit of reading in the encoded format).

Answer (score 2):

The method described by Jonathan in his answer is in fact what the C++ compiler did for the first few years of its life; the translator was called [cfront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront).

For printing out data types that aren't native C types, customizing stack traces, and displaying info about custom threading implementations, you can go a fair distance by writing python code to extend GDB. This can be effective whether your compiler's target is C or native code. `Go` (which produces native code with its `gc` compiler) provides [runtime-gdb.py](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/runtime-gdb.py), for example.

Comment: I actually noticed Go cooperates with GDB when I was doing my research on this topic. Thanks for pointing me to the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the common approach to this when a compiler targets C?

There are no common compilers that target C and provide debugging info in the higher-level language. I can't think of any approach that would work at all.

> I am looking at GDB's pretty printer. Will that be a possible solution to me?

You may be able to create some "smoke and mirrors" illusion that you are debugging the higher-level language. I doubt you'll find the illusion that you can build that way satisfactory.